# How does doping affect the color of a semiconductor?

Tags: visible-light, semiconductor-physics, spectroscopy

Does P/N doping a semiconductor affect the color in some straightforward manner?  Say the material starts as a yellow color and it is p doped, what can we expect from this information or what information do we really need.

Comment: Diamond does change color. Silicon is dark and shiny regardless of doping.

Answer (score 1):

Dopant affects band gap of material. The band gap determines the wavelength of light that the material absorbs. The color of material depends on what light it absorbs.
Maybe P/N dope affects color of material. If you draw the band gap of material using any method (Density functional Theory or etc), you can predict color of material some extent.
In real world, color of material is more complex than I said. I don't know if it can predict the color of matter perfectly.

Comment: No. Doping does not change the band gap.

Comment: I was wrong. In 2D BP, potassium doping changes band gap, so I did think it is general phenomenon.

Comment: @Pieter Doping does change the band gap technically though?  Although it will depend on thermal effects, I believe P doping introduces empty electron holes which are easily excited into, but this does decrease the band gap does it not?  It may be a slight effect though.

Comment: @TristanMaxson Doping introduces states in the band gap. Shallow donors or shallow acceptors are close to band edges, but the concentrations are far too low to change the band gap.